# Submit iOS application linked to iOS 6

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Can I submit an application linked with iOS 6 on the App Store now that iOS 7 is out?

I've read the guidelines to submitting an application on the App Store, but didn't find anything on this subject. I assume Apple wouldn't forbid it, but I would like to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I’ve done it and my application was accepted by Apple.